# The existence of a convergent subseries of the harmonic series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have just learned that there are convergent subseries of the harmonic series like Kempner series. How can I prove the existence of such a subseries without construction?

Comment: I wouldn't know, all proofs I know are constructive. May I ask why you think you need a non-constructive proof?

Comment: By "such a subseries", do you mean something like the Kempner series (i.e., you look at $\frac{1}{n}$ for only those $n$ missing some numbers in their decimal expansion)? Or do you mean you want to show that _some_ subseries of the harmonic series converges? In either case, I agree with professor vector -- what do you mean by "without construction"?

Comment: Like proving the existence of the solution of a PDE without actually solve the equations. I would like to know if there is a way to just show the existence.